# Image getting pixelated when used as part of an animation in iPhone animation

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-animation, core-graphics

After countless tries I got my animation animating right (Why oh why is the layer's coordinate system Y flipped from the view's coordinate system, I will never guess) but it seems that it degrades the image quality for some reason:

[image]

(green circled are examples of the original good quality images, the red circled is to emphasize the difference. [original image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QanZ1.png)).

Close up:

[image]

(The lower images are as supposed to be, except the left one. The rest are pixelated.)

The code I'm using (approximately, you can see the exact one in the image.):

```
CGImageRef *ir = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something"].CGImage;
CALayer *cl = [CALayer layer];
cl.contents = ir;

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
anim.duration = 5;
anim.autoreverses = NO;
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

anim.fromValue = **something**
anim.toValue = **anotherthing**
[cl addAnimation:anim forKey: @"fallDown"];
```

My questions:

1. Why is there such a difference between the images? How do I fix it?
2. How is my code? I just can't find enough examples / explanations about the animation types and all stuff you can do with it (for example all of the animatable properties). And I am learning the SDK by myself (I have iPhone in Action but it's quite basic) and there is no one I know to review my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend had a stroke of genius: my image files were huge. When I switched to using smaller files (resized) everything looked the same. I'm guessing there is some resizing issue here.

Thanks RL... :)